# How to add Bootstrap columns to JQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code and I want to add Bootstrap's columns to `dataSelected` and `dataOptionSelected` so that there is proper spacing between them. How do I go about doing this?

```
// col-md-7
var dataSelected = $("#dataPicker option:selected").val();

// col-md-5
var dataOptionSelected = $("#dataOptionPicker option:selected").val();

newDataRow.innerHTML = dataSelected + " " + dataOptionSelected;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the details with a bootstrap row and their columns nested within as follows:

```
newDataRow.innerHTML = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-7'>" 
+ dataSelected + "</div><div class='col-md-5'>" 
+ dataOptionSelected + "</div></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any class to an element with the addClass function, for example:

```
$('#dataOptionPicker').addClass('col-md-4');
```

The addClass function can take several classes seperated by a comma. For more information refer to this: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: `$("#dataPicker option:selected").val().addClass('col-md-6')` produces this error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).addClass is not a function**

Comment: Thats because the result of `val()` is a primitive value and not a jquey object

Comment: @b11 when using `.val()` you're trying to get the value of the picker. To use the addClass function you need to get the element by its ID (or any other attribute) then add the class to it. If you still want to use `val()` then you have to write two different statements. The first is used to get the value of the picker and the second to add the CSS class to the picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up newDataRow in a div with bootstrap row and columns structure like below:

```
// col-md-7
var dataSelected = $('#dataPicker option:selected').val();

// col-md-5
var dataOptionSelected = $('#dataOptionPicker option:selected').val();

newDataRow.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-7">' + dataSelected + '</div><div class="col-md-5">' + dataOptionSelected + '</div></div>';
```